# Protocol reference in swift is throwing segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, xcode, date, swift, calendar

I'm trying to create a Date and Calendar implementation in Swift making heavy use of protocol, but it started throwing segmentation fault 11 in every approach. My current one is this:

```
protocol CalendarUnit {
  typealias C: Calendar
  init(_ date: Date<C>)
}

protocol Calendar {
  typealias Second: CalendarUnit
}

struct GregorianCalendar: Calendar {

  struct Second: CalendarUnit {
  }
}

struct Date<C: Calendar> {
  let timestamp: Int

  var second: C.Second { return C.Second(self) }
}
```

A suspicion is because of the recursion of both protocols bu not sure how to implement this section in another way. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

EDIT

Could also use type constriction between the initializer of calendarunit, and the calendar to which it belongs.

```
protocol CalendarUnit {
  init<C>(date: Date<C>)
}

protocol Calendar {

  typealias Year: CalendarUnit
}

struct GregorianCalendar: Calendar {

  struct Year: CalendarUnit {

    init<C>(date: Date<C>) {
    }
  }
}

struct JulianCalendar: Calendar {

  struct Year: CalendarUnit {

    init<GregorianCalendar>(date: Date<GregorianCalendar>) {
    }
  }
}

struct Date<C: Calendar> {
}
```

In the example I can insert any calendar (julian inside a gregorian) and will satisfy the protocol need but it does not guarantee it's the same calendar. Is there a way to enforce this restriction, preferably without having to repeat the name of the calendar in the typealias?.

Comment: My best bet is that the compiler crashes because of the recursion. Either they don't support this yet, or it's a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Why do you need C : Calendar on the CalendarUnit?. Can you explain a little bit more what "Second" and "C" means in your implementation?

Comment: I updated the question, is to be able to create a date struct that can ask its calendar for the number of seconds it represents. But to make it more modular, each type will have it's own initializer, logic, etc and calendar will be the holder of these component types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: llvm throwing segmentation fault is *always* a bug in the compiler, regardless of the correctness of your syntax, and you should fill a radar for it.

Regarding to your question: I don't think you need the recursive definition. You can achieve what *I think* you need with an implementation like this:

```
import Foundation

protocol CalendarUnit {
  init<T>(_ date: Date<T>)
}

protocol Calendar {
  typealias Second: CalendarUnit
}

struct GregorianCalendar: Calendar {

  struct Second: CalendarUnit {
      init<T>(_ date: Date<T>) {
          println("Initialized")
      }
  }
}

struct Date<C: Calendar> {
  let timestamp: Int

  var second: C.Second { return C.Second(self) }
}

let test = Date<GregorianCalendar>(timestamp: 0)
let seconds = test.second
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much. I hope Apple corrects many of the compiler bugs soon, it's frustrating not to know if it's me or the compiler that is failing.

Comment: Is there a way that to constraint that the T in the init inside CalendarUnit be the same as the Calendar that possesses the CalendarUnit?

Comment: Just to clarify: Can you add an example for when they are not different?

Comment: Right now doesn't matter much because there is only one kind of dictionary, but if I add julian i could create the gregorian month using a julian calendar. I edited the question to showcase what I'm talking about. It satisfies the constraints of the protocol but it's clear to see that something is wrong

Comment: What you are experiencing now is a funny situation: in your example you are using `init<GregorianCalendar>(date: Date<GregorianCalendar>)` but want to guess what `GregorianCalendar.self` type is? It's actually a JulianCalendar type!. The reason being that the generics syntax takes any name for the type. You are naming it `GregorianCalendar` but you could actually name it `WhateverYouWant` (I happened to name it `T`). Try to do: `println("\(GregorianCalendar.self is JulianCalendar.Type)")` inside your `CalendarUnit` init of the example. You'll see that's `true`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me understand that. Sadly, it looks that to be able to enforce the type restriction I'm gonna have to wait for protocol recursion to be fixed. because something like this could still happen:
let date = Date<JulianCalendar>()
GregorianCalendar.Year(date: date)
Thanks a bunch anyway.

Comment: You are right that it's possible to create a year like that, but you could also set the initializers of your calendar impl as private and force access these properties from your main Date<> struct

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try that when I get home, and report back. So frustrated when Swift 1.2 came out and didn't have protocol recursion. :(